# how to install and use php 7.0.22 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

I was using Linux Mint 18.3 and I upgraded to Linux Mint 19 based on Ubuntu 18.04. My problem is I have a PHP rest api which was built using PHP 7.0.22 and now it's doing weird things.

I've googled for a solution and I found nothing about PHP 7.0.22 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I must say that PHP is unknow for me and I can't tell what I did since I ran a lot of commands, but now if I hit:

`$ php -v`

it responds:

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I went into /usr/lib/php/20151012/ and there is no xdebug.so file. How can I solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: First thing that I'd try running `sudo apt install php-xdebug` (it looks like PHP's configuration thinks that it's installed, even though it isn't). It sounds like you're implying that the PHP version changed between Linux Mint 18.3 and 19; what had it been before?

Comment: I did it but it installed php 7.2.x

Comment: Extension loading conf.ini files reside in `/etc/php/*/*/conf.d/`

Comment: PHP 7.0 is end of life in a month. No more security updates. Move to 7.2.

Comment: @miken32 good to know

Comment: If you rely on a specific php version that is not the currently supported in your distro, I highly recommend running this in a docker container. Check out the official php docker hub repository. https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: @HåkenLid I think that is a good idea. Also I set my sources list to point to Ubuntu 16.04 and then installed php-xdebug and it worked for me. Maybe not the best or the prettiest solution but worked for me.